# Not able to drop Hive table pointing to Azure Storage account that no longer exists

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight

I am using Hive based on HDInsight Hadoop cluster -- Hadoop 2.7 (HDI 3.6).

We have some old Hive tables that point to some very storage accounts that don't exist any more. But these tables still point to these storage locations , basically the Hive Metastore still contain references to the deleted storage accounts. If I try to drop such a hive table , I get an error

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: No credentials found for account <deletedstorage>.blob.core.windows.net in the configuration, and its container data is not accessible using anonymous credentials. Please check if the container exists first. If it is not publicly available, you have to provide account credentials.)
```

Manipulating the Hive Metatstore directly is risky as it could land the Metastore in an invalid state.

Is there any way to get rid of these orphan tables?

Comment: Is the Refresh/invalidate metadata applied on those tables?https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html

Comment: No -- also no such command as "invalidate metadata" exists in Hive. I think you are providing Impala commands,

Comment: Did you check the refresh command?

Comment: Please check this- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3cca1765-ef2a-4ba5-a827-d6ac7bb240c8/azureexception-unable-to-access-container-using-anonymous-credentials-and-no-credentials-found-for?forum=hdinsight

Comment: no refresh command in this version of hive

Comment: Looks like it's a glitch and there is no way to delete these phantom tables